# How to match multiple rows of different columns in excel

Tags: excel, compare, match

I got an Excel like this:

```
---------
| 1 | a |
---------
| 2 | b |
---------
| 3 | c |
---------
| 4 | d |
---------
| 5 | e | 
---------
```

and a table like this:

```
---------
| 4 | d |
---------
| 3 | k |
---------
| 2 | b |
---------
| 1 | a |
---------
```

Now I want to check: If the data of the first column is the same in both tables, then check if the second column also has the same in that row. So of the example above, it would give a result like this:

```
---------------------
| 1 | a | correct   |
---------------------
| 2 | b | correct   |
---------------------
| 3 | c | wrong     |
---------------------
| 4 | d | correct   |
---------------------
| 5 | e | not found |
---------------------
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A1,F:G,2,FALSE)=B1,"Correct","Wrong"),"Not Found")
```

[image]